# Does SQL injection apply to WMI queries?

Tags: sql, wmi, sql-injection

Is SQL injection a threat with WMI?

### For example:

Given the following code, if `domainName` is provided externally and not sanitised, what could a malicious attacker potentially achieve?

```
string domainName = "user-inputted-domain.com";
string wql = "SELECT * 
    FROM MicrosoftDNS_ATYPE
    WHERE OwnerName = '" + domainName + "'";
// perform WMI query here...
```

If it is a threat, which I imagine it is, what would be the best way to defend against it in lieu of not using a normal parameterised query like I would with LINQ? Would simply stripping out any [`'`] characters do the trick?

And on a different note, are there any LINQ extensions for querying WMI which would address this?

---

**Edit:** Found the [`SelectQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class. Haven't tried it yet, but it seems to have more robust query-building capabilities, e.g. a `Condition` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's vulnerable in the same way, in that they could input any arbitrary conditions after that.  Think if they put in `foo' OR SomeOtherField='bar` as their input.  However, I don't think you can do multiple WQL queries in one single string so it may not have the same "attack surface" so to speak, since WQL is such a small subset of SQL.

So, the attack method would still work, yes.  What exact risks that exposes you to depends on some of the following things:

- Could a would-be attacker prematurely terminate your WQL statement and then insert their own?
- Could they adjust the filter to release more data than you want (as I mentioned above)?
- probably lots of others I haven't thought of